# Where can I find a study on the amount of different word frequencies in a corpus?

Tags: natural-language-processing

I need to know how many different values the frequency of a certain word in a corpus can there be for a natural language processing problem. Is there any study or site that has such estimation?

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking.  I suggest you break the question down into smaller pieces (maybe defining your terms and/or providing necessary background and motivation), give an example or two, and tell us what you've tried and where you've looked.  Naively, it looks like the answer is: the frequency could be anything.  If you're thinking of the number 42, I can come up with a corpus where the word "sasquatch" appears 42 times.. and the same is true for any number other than 42, too.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking directly refers to [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval). Information Retrieval directly creates models for such things as frequency of words in a corpus and so on.

In a corpus, different indicators are estimated in order to create a score. Two indicators are predominant in those models :

- **Inverse document frequency (idf)**

This model aims at attenuating words that appear too often and considered irrelevant to judge the score of a word.

$ idf_{t} = log\frac{N}{df_{t}}$ where $N$ stands for the total of document in a collection and $df_{t}$  the number of documents in a collector that contain the term $t$

- **Term frequency (tf)**

This is the most basic way to modelize word frequency in a corpus. It can be computed by saying that:

$tf_{t,d} = \frac{t_{occ}}{N}$ where $t_{occ}$ is the occurence of the term divided by the number of words in the document.

More information on this subject can be found here :

[Scoring, term weighting and the
vector space model](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/06vect.pdf)